# PostgreSQL, plpython3u function. os.getenv does not find the environment variable

Tags: postgresql, shell, environment-variables, psql, plpython

I get the below situation with `PostgreSQL` `plpython3u` function.

I've recently added a environment variable to my shell startup file. The `env | grep MY_VAR` command returns `MY_VAR=/path/`. But when I run a `select * from my_func();` query from a psql command line, the function says that the environment variable is `None`.

```
create or replace function my_func()
returns int as
$$
import os
 for k, v in os.environ.items():
  plpy.info(k + ':' + v)
MY_VAR = os.getenv('MY_VAR')
if MY_VAR is None:
 plpy.info('was not found')
 return -1
plpy.info('MY_VAR:' + MY_VAR)
return 0
$$ language 'plpython3u';
returns int AS
```

The `for k, v in os.environ.items(): ...` prints all variables except the one I search for. The `MY_VAR` gets missed somehow.

Please advice. Why did the function can't find `MY_VAR`?

***Update***

The `\! env` command in `psql` command prompt also lists `MY_VAR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the `PostgreSQL` server only reads envinronment variables once, upon the main server process start. I had to restart the server to get access to full envinronment varaibles list.